# Using Kendall's W or Kendall's Tau?

Tags: correlation, dataset, multiple-comparisons, consistency, kendall-tau

So I have a dataset of 5,000 observations annotated by two respondents each, which comes out to 10,000 unique annotations. In these 10,000 unique annotations, I had 600 unique respondents, with the average number of annotations per respondent being 15. Each observation is annotated across five different attributes, three of which are measured between 1 and 5 and two of which are measured as either a 1 or a 0. My question is, can I use Kendall's W or Kendall's Tau to measure respondent consistency over my data?

From the Kendall's W examples I've seen it looks like to measure consistency, you need a set of judges to annotate the same batch of observations, so for example, 5 judges annotate the same 10 observations and we measure consistency across the annotations. In my case, however, I don't have a batch of observations annotated by the same $m$ judges because the number of annotations per respondents varies and each observation only has two annotations. Can I still use Kendall's W?

Looking into Kendall's Tau, I notice that it is used primarily to assess the consistency between two different annotations. So say I have attributes $A$ and $B$ that are annotated for all my observations, Kendall's Tau would measure the relationship between the annotated values of $A$ and $B$. Would it make sense to use Kendall's Tau to look at the relationships between the 5 attributes each observation is annotated with?

Is there another way to measure respondent consistency in my specific case? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!